# Need help styling matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this simple matplotlib graph, and I'm having lots of trouble figuring out two things: How to change the background color, and how to make the gridlines solid instead of dashes.
Specifically, is there a way to use a custom color code for the background color?

```
import sys
import matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas

x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
y=np.array([9,8,7,6,5,4])
y2=np.array([4,4,4,4,4,3])
y3=([6,6,6,5,5,3])
plt.plot(x, y, label='Phaser 1')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='Phaser 3')
plt.plot(x, y3, label='Phaser 2')
plt.plot(x, y2)
plt.plot(x, y3)
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Die Roll')
plt.ylabel('Damage')
plt.title('Phaser damage at range 0')
plt.colors()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid-lines, use the argument *linestyle*. For background use the *axisbg* keyword (can also be a HTML color code e.g. #FFF999) to subplot before making your actual plot:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.subplot('111', axisbg='#FFF999')
>>> plt.plot([1,2,3])
>>> plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='b', linestyle='-')
>>> plt.show()
```